# Curl to prompt a User Name and Password

Tags: curl

I have a password protect web folder on my site, I am fetching that folder on another domain using `Curl`, what I want is: when I try to open the URL it should ask me the user name and password, instead of asking it display the "Authorization Required".

Example:

- http://www.example.com/admin (password protected using htpasswrd htaccess)
- http://www.2nddomain.com/admin

If I try to access the "a" url it ask me for the user name password. Fine.
but it doesn't ask me for the user name and password on "b" (using curl here).

Any Idea?

In Short: I want to make `Curl` ask for the User/Password prompt.

Regards

I am not sure, if it is possible or not? but if it's possible so please let me know how, otherwise I will close this as "Invalid"

Comment: Why not just prompt for a login before using Curl?

Comment: hmm that would be cool, my second domain is hosted on a Plesk server, which doesn't allow me to have htaccess over there.. and secondly, may be I don't want to have any password file on my second domain or any scripting...

Answer (score 72):

Try the following like :

```
curl -su 'user' <url>
```

It should prompt `password` for the user

Comment: I tried this, and it just tells me that it can't resolve host "username".

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, worked for me.

Comment: All well and good but the OP wanted to know how to prompt for user id & password your solution only does the password

Answer (score 8):

Examples:

--user

```
curl -v --user myName:mySecret http://example.com/foo/bar
```

-u

```
curl -v -u myName:mySecret http://example.com/foo/bar
```

(example for Minh Nguyen see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826658/3411766)

```
curl -v -su 'myName' http://example.com/foo/bar
```

asks for the pw of user 'myName'.

Answer (score 2):

for .htaccess style password protection, You can code the userid password as in:

curl -u userid:password http://.......

Comment: hmm, that a correct approach but I want a Password Prompt, never want to enter the user name or password in a file hosted on my second domain

Comment: Not sure about your environment, if I do it in a shell script. It is something like. read -p "Userid: " userid ; read -s -p "Password: " passwd; curl -u $userid:$passwd http://......

Comment: We need a http Prompt here.. instead of hard coded user name and passwrd

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly, on the "b" site you want to access the "a" site on the server side? and you want the "b" to generate a password prompt on the client's browser? You need a CGI on the "b" site to do that.

Comment: if you don't need a .htaccess style prompt, you can always write an html form and have the user type in userid and password at the "b" site and your code pass the information to the "a" site when you process the form at the "b" server.

Comment: If you use any of these methods (including read -s method and any tricks around this), your password can be found in the system, process table: /proc or using strace -p <pid>

Answer (score 2):

-H 'Authorization: Basic user:pass'
user:pass must be encoded in base64

Comment: That solution doesn't prompt for a password.  You have the password on the `curl` command line.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cookies there I think. The steps would be:

1. If you try to curl "http://www.2nddomain.com/admin" with no cookies, it can return you a html login form.
2. Your form's action would point to 2nd server and if the credentials were right, set the cookie there and return (redirect) to server 1.
3. And if you curl again, you'd check the cookie on the other side and in this case, it could read that cookie and return you the admin page output instead.

Comment: Nopes, it doesn't return the login prompt.. that what I needed!

Comment: Ok but you need to write it yourself. using php or whatever you got there.